# How to stick the header area at the top of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my header area section of my template. i want to stick the menu bar and logo at the top. I tried a lot for all most 4 days.But i couldn't.I use sticky.js plugin.But it wouldn't happen.What's wrong with my code?I couldn't understand.I use parallax in the header section.Is that for the problem.

```css
.parallax-window {
  background: transparent;
}

.parallax_bg {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_area parallax-window" data-z-index="1" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/header_img/header_background.jpg">
  <div class="parallax_bg">
    <div class="top_area">
      <div class="header_area">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row" id="navbar-example">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="logo">
                <a href="#"><img src="img/header_img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-10">
              <div class="main_menu">

                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
                </div>


                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#slider">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#food_about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#igredients">Igredients</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#food_menu">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#reviews">Reviews</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#reservations">Reservations</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="social_links">
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="header_text_area">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
              <div class="header_text">
                <h2>the right ingredients <br /> for the right food</h2>
                <a href="#" class="btn-filled">BOOK A TABLE</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn-filled yellow-color-btn">SEE THE MENU</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no tried for do this with simple `css`, or even `sticky.js` !

Comment: Try not using parallax for navbar or logo, you can use it for jumbotron or header or in banner.

Comment: thanks. your information is really helpfull for me

Answer (score 0):

Try navbar-fixed-top in class of header.

Comment: thanks man it's working. simple code only. I am newbie in this sector.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```css
.parallax-window {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top_area parallax-window" data-z-index="1" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/header_img/header_background.jpg">
  <div class="parallax_bg">
    <div class="top_area">
      <div class="header_area">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row" id="navbar-example">
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <div class="logo">
                <a href="#"><img src="img/header_img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-10">
              <div class="main_menu">

                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
                </div>


                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#slider">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#food_about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#igredients">Igredients</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#food_menu">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#reviews">Reviews</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#reservations">Reservations</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="social_links">
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="header_text_area">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
              <div class="header_text">
                <h2>the right ingredients <br /> for the right food</h2>
                <a href="#" class="btn-filled">BOOK A TABLE</a>
                <a href="#" class="btn-filled yellow-color-btn">SEE THE MENU</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```